# how to get evenly spread out breaks with bdscale and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot using bdscale package and the `scale_x_bd` function however the breaks are getting clumped together:

[image]

How do I get them so they're spread out evenly?

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(bdscale)

x = data.frame(date  = seq.Date(from = today() - 100, to = today(), by = 'day'))
x$idx = 1:nrow(x)

ggplot(x, aes(x = date, y = idx)) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_point() +
  bdscale::scale_x_bd(business.dates = x$date, max.major.breaks = 10, max.minor.breaks = 10)
```

Comment: The `bdscale` package hasn't been updated in nearly four years. It's possible this issue was occurring with earlier versions of ggplot2 or that `bdscale` doesn't work properly with newer versions of ggplot2. You might need to look at the `bdscale` code and modify it or find a different way to exclude non-business dates.

Comment: You could [open an issue](https://github.com/dvmlls/bdscale/issues) at the package development site and see if the package author has any suggestions.